# Web Application fails to load an iframe in IE with error as "Navigation to the web page was cancelled."

Tags: javascript, html, internet-explorer, iframe, internet-explorer-11

The Web application works fine in IE 10 and below versions. But in IE 11, it fails to load iframe. In the console the error is "SEC7111: HTTPS security is compromised by res://ieframe.dll/sslnavcancel.htm". I tried to search for a fix but none of them helped. I have enabled the config for IFRAME in the settings.

On the GUI, "Content was blocked because it was not signed by a valid security certificate. For more information, see “About Certificate Errors” in Internet Explorer Help." is displayed.

I tried few changes in settings.Now in the GUI,
**Navigation to the web page was cancelled.**

Please suggest me some what needs to be done.

Comment: please post the code where the error is happening so we can help

Comment: I cant do, it a client code. I don't think so its a code issue.I guess its a IE setting issue. Since the code works fine in IE10.

Comment: You guess it is a **setting** issue because the problem occurs when you change **versions** of the browser?

Comment: The error message seems clear enough: "Content was blocked because it was not signed by a valid security certificate". Make sure the content is accessed over SSL with an appropriate certificate.

Comment: possible duplicate of [IE: HTTPS security is compromised by res://ieframe.dll/sslnavcancel.htm](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24194855/ie-https-security-is-compromised-by-res-ieframe-dll-sslnavcancel-htm)

Comment: @Quentin by "change versions of the browser" do you mean manually changing the document mode to Edge?

Comment: I have enable the IFRAME setting, display mixed content also. The certificate is also proper

Comment: @user2764467 — No, I mean changing from IE10 to IE11.

Comment: Yes I have upgraded IE10 to IE11.